# What exactly is a pointee and what is it's type?

Tags: c, pointers, pointee

For instance, let's consider this C code:

```
int x;
const int *p = &x;
```

`p` is now a non-const pointer to const int. But what is the type of the pointee? Is it `int` or `const int`? I've been searching but I have not found a precise definition.

Just to avoid confusion, `const int *p` means that p is a pointer to `const int` while `int * const p` means that p is a const pointer to int.

I did find [this](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pointee):

> ### Noun
>
> **pointee** (plural **pointees**)
>
> (computing) The data or object referenced by a pointer.

But it's not precise enough to answer the question of the pointee type.

Comment: Hmmm ... the (effective) *pointee* type is `const int` ... and the underlying *pointee* type is `int`. Maybe relevant [C11 6.2.5p20](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p20) discusses "derived types"

Answer (score 0):

The pointee is the object the pointer points to. In this case the pointee is `x` which is of type `int`.

Think about it this way: `p` is a constant "view" into the object `x`, aka via `p` you can only read `x`, but that doesn't change the fact that `x` is mutable.

Anyway don't sweat too much about it. "Pointee" is not a terminology that's used too much, and I even doubt it is defined in the standard.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the pointer p is what is left of p: `const int *`. The type of the pointee is what is left of *p: `const int`. In the program you have to comment const to be able to modify the pointee:

```
#include "stdio.h"

main()
{
    int i = 42;
    /* const */  int *p = &i;
    *p = 43;
    printf("i: %d", i);
}
```